Lowest processable signal level after FFT with given noise level
I have the following problem:
I have to amplify a low voltage level signal which is the output signal of a sensor. The signal is always a sine wave with f = 1 kHz and no DC offset. After amplifying this sine wave the output is digitalized with a PC sound card.
By my calculations at the output of my amplifier I will have around 3 mVrms noise (mostly white). What is the lowest signal level that I can detect precisely (let's say around +-5%) after running an FFT on the sampled dataset?
Sound card specs:

24 bit
192 kHz maximum sampling freq
+/- 1V input voltage range

I would be grateful if You could include optimal settings in your answers or recommend me a book/paper where I can read about this topic. Thanks in advance!

There is no lower bound on how weak of a signal you can detect if you're willing to wait long enough recording signal.

@user1850479 so if I collect lots of samples, the SNR will increase due to the random nature of noise?

First observation: the FFT is simply the wrong tool here. You're only interested in a single frequency at 1/192 of your sampling rate. To build an FFT-based estimator for that where as much energy of the tone ends up in a single FFT bin, the FFT length would have to be a multiple of 192 – but you're really not interested in any of these 192 (or 384, or 3×192, or 4×192 or…) FFT bins aside from that single one that corresponds to 1 kHz.
So, don't use an FFT where you want a bandpass filter. The Goertzel algorithm is mathematically 100% identical to the FFT, but only computes a single bin, at much lower effort than doing the whole FFT.
But as said, it doesn't make a difference whether you calculate most of your bins in vain or use Goertzel. What does not work as well is using a power-of-2 length FFT: Because your frequency of interest is not an integer multiple of \$\frac{1}{2^N}\$ of your sampling rate, that would lead to leakage and hence to significant degradation of detection performance.

What is the lowest signal level that I can detect precisely (let's say around +-5%) after running an FFT on the sampled dataset?

What you're saying is that the noise amplitude in your bin containing 1 kHz must not be more than 5% of the signal amplitude; that's 1/20, or -26 dB.
1/20 of the amplitude is 1/400 of the power (and in power terms, that's also -26 dB, because of the way how decibel are defined for amplitude and power entities).

I will have around 3 mVrms noise (mostly white).

OK, we need to talk about noise for a moment:

rms: Root mean square, in other words, for a zero-mean noise process, the standard deviation. Which is the square root of variance, which is proportional to physical power.
white: that means that, acting as if you were doing the minimum viable FFT, a 192-point FFT, the noise power on average distributes evenly over all 192 bins in your FFT. So, the variance of (3 mVrms)² distributes over 192 bins. Converting 3 mV to a decibel-of-Volt scale gives us -50.5 dBV in total, or -96 dBV per bin¹.

But: RMS is just that, a root mean square. It's an averaged measure. Noise is not deterministic. You can never preclude any realization of the noise having a MUCH higher power in that bin at some point! However if we assume your noise to be well-behaved (for example, the noise being both white and Gaussian), the likelihood of the average power over an observation being, say, 10% larger than the overall variance  is very small. But you can never be sure. It's noise. It's random, by definition.
So, anyway, for your noise to be 5% (=1/20) of your signal amplitude in a 192-point Goertzel or a 192-point FFT, or 1/400 of signal power on average, your signal power would need to be -96 dBV + 26 dB = -70 dBV = 0.316 mVrms.
It's less than noise power! But that's easy to explain: Your noise distributes evenly over all frequencies, but we only look at a very narrow part of the frequency spectrum, where we measure your tone's amplitude.

¹ This is a pretty low noise power, and I congratulate you to building a measurement setup that can achieve it!

a quadrature demodulator would also get you a single complex frequency component. As the OP is interested in weak signals, with long averaging times, Goertzel algo is more prone to saturation and rounding issues even with floating point arithmetic. A quad demodulator at 1 kHz will not accumulate larger numbers in contrast.

@tobalt Sure, you need to design it for the purpose, but if you can do a stable N-point FFT, you can do a stable equivalent Goertzel in your code (i.e, an N-FFT would contain the value after N iterations of Goertzeling; you can reasonably say you reset the Goertzel each N samples to 0 state to get equivalent results). In the end, you're of course right, it's a recursive form. Also note that I think there's good literature on error "dithering" when noise is present, which kind of alleviates the accuracy issues a bit. You're making a good point!

Thanks for your help, I will dive deeper into the topic.

If a phase reference is available this would be a perfect application for phase-sensitive or lock-in detection.

You don't need a phase reference, if you use a quadrature demodulator. But you need a frequency reference. I suppose it is available, because I assume that the 1kHz might be created with the same soundcard too.
